# Why do we use past tense verbs to describe present events?

Tags: tense

I have color vision deficiency. So would I say "I wish I wasn't color vision deficient" or "I wish I'm not color vision deficient"? I think the latter is correct, but the former sounds correct. Have I been using my tense wrong? It's not like I was color vision deficient; I still am.

Comment: It's odd isn't it.  BillJ calls it "modal preterite", the past (or preterite) tense indicates the modallity: it indicates the remote chance of the wish coming true. This use is related to the second and third conditionals.

Comment: One of your questions was "why?" In Old English and early Middle English, the subjunctive had a different ending than the past tense (at least for many verbs). However, time has worn away the endings so now the subjunctive is almost always the same as the past tense, and some grammarians (whose suggestions BillJ follows) have stopped calling it the subjunctive. So now, some people call it *the past subjunctive*, some *the modal preterite*, and some *the irrealis.*